# Issue with Column footer and Summary bands

Tags: jasper-reports

I am creating invoices with *JasperReports*.

I have a *Detail* section that has the list of all items followed by a column footer which has Totals, Tax etc., and then the return policy in the *Summary* section.

I want to always ensure that the *Detail* is followed by *Column footer* followed by *Summary* bands. How can we ensure this? I found that sometimes the *Summary* comes before the *Column footer*.

Can someone throw some light on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There really is not much of a solution to this at the moment as it seems to be by-design and not a bug (personally I think they should have an option for this). Your options at the moment though are:

- Create a Report Group (this is essentially a dummy report group,
  doesn't really matter). Move your `Column Footer` contents into the 
  `Group Footer` band, and leave your Summary in the `Summary` band.
  This seemed to work in my limited tests, and I would try it first.
- Set `Float Column Footer` and `Summary on new Page` to true under the
  main report properties. This has the unfortunate side effect that the
  summary will always be printed on a second page regardless if
  everything could fit on one.
- Set `Float Column Footer` to true and move your `Summary` section to
  the `Last Page Footer` band. This means it will only be printed once,
  but the content will be oriented towards the bottom of the last page.

**Edit:** For the shed some light on this part of the question. It is by design. The Column Footer is seen/treated as essentially a specialized Page footer. So body content (detail band, summary band, etc.) are placed on the page above it always. The only time it does not seem to happen is when the summary is printed on a new page, after the last Column Footer has been printed. So it is by design.

Comment: Your first solution works for one page report only. If report has more than one page, then it will print only in last page. May be a partial solution. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: If you give up on having a column footer per page, there is another option than the report group: Simply delete your column footer and place its contents at the top of the summary band

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for answers to this silly formatting question for hours, and I think I might have found a *useable* solution:

- move your Column Footer content to the Page Footer and,
- create a Last Page Footer but set its width to 1 pixel with no content inside

This allowed me to have some borders/subtotals at the bottom of every column, whilst ignoring the footer-before-summary/total-before-subtotal problem on the last page because the Last Page Footer *overwrites* the Page Footer (summary) content.

Answer (score 0):

Add a last page Footer , in that add the content of your column footer after that increase band width and add the summary content into that(last page footer) and remove the content from the summary band.