# Gap between detail and column footer bands even after setting "Float Column Footer" to true

Tags: jasper-reports

I am creating a jasper report showing some person names. I need to show the number of persons in the list at the bottom.

The problem I am facing is I am getting a small gap between persons list and the label "Total Candidates".

For the reference, please check below image:
[image: Gap marked in red box]

In the beginning, column footer was getting shown at the end of page, leaving a lot of gap. Then I found few good StackOverflow links:
1) [Issue with Column footer and Summary bands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377178/issue-with-column-footer-and-summary-bands)
2) [Jasper Reports - how to get column footer to appear directly below details band](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233495/jasper-reports-how-to-get-column-footer-to-appear-directly-below-details-band)
which suggested to set "Float Column Footer" to true. After doing that, the gap reduced and my column footer is almost below the detail band. But still, as shown in the picture, there is some gap remaining, which I don't know how to remove.

Edit: Here is my jrxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isFloatColumnFooter="true" uuid="b7718df8-d1d7-46e7-9a66-7d3fe24c720c">
    <parameter name="ReportName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="firstName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[firstName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[id]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="lastName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[lastName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="middleName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[middleName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <title>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="42" uuid="b6eaae95-75f5-4b33-978b-8afd7f9ecfee"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="20"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{ReportName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="32" height="20" uuid="3dfe1b88-b77c-465e-bc1d-d96223c69692"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Sr. No.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="32" y="0" width="188" height="20" uuid="96add808-7f90-405d-93fc-ae64596df9e3"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[First Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="220" y="0" width="188" height="20" uuid="dd5aa422-a23c-4a4c-a464-9e927503c342"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Middle Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="408" y="0" width="147" height="20" uuid="e7894574-4f95-4a04-b54b-16f636dc453c"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Last Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="32" height="20" uuid="b0a9a50f-f275-4802-ba80-04559e57c75e"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="32" y="0" width="188" height="20" uuid="4ea4f73b-06bb-4553-848b-eecdc6be51b2"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{firstName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="220" y="0" width="188" height="20" uuid="d2ea4610-7ee7-4921-babe-6d9040592843"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{middleName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="408" y="0" width="147" height="20" uuid="045272ac-1387-49c6-a4e1-237725e08269"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{lastName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="79" height="20" uuid="5a71d074-89c3-4b70-ae90-840cb37b45e8"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Total Candidates:]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Any suggestions would be really appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you have some empty group footer, hard to say without seeing the jrxml..., you can also consider using the group footer, and place your totale candiates there.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I will try to use group footer. Thanks Petter for the suggestion.

Comment: //yes your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377178/issue-with-column-footer-and-summary-bands

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<summary>
    <band height="0" splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
```

or remove the tag completely.